# "GENERAL FAILURE" ping 127.0.0.1 after `route delete` and `route add` restoring

Tags: windows, loopback, network-interface, routetable

alt spelling: https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/restart-software-loopback-interface.2880183/
is there a way to restart `Software Loopback Interface` without restarting windows ?

to reproduce:

```
route delete 127.0.0.1 0.0.0.0 if 1
route add 127.0.0.1 0.0.0.0 if 1
ping 127.0.0.1
```

output (tested on win11):

```
Pinging 127.0.0.1 with 32 bytes of data:
General failure.
General failure.
General failure.
General failure.

Ping statistics for 127.0.0.1:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),
```

___
background information:
using `route print`, `if 1` (interface 1) is:

```
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
```

Comment: Why on earth did you do such a thing? NB There is no [tag:network-programming] here. Off topic.

Answer (score 1):

this probably doesn't "restart" the interface but it does the job:

```
netsh interface ip set address "Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1" static address=127.0.0.1 mask=255.0.0.0 gateway=none
```

output:

```
>ping 127.0.0.1

Pinging 127.0.0.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 127.0.0.1:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```